# javascript timer to change content of a text

Tags: javascript, html, timer, setinterval, parseint

In html I have mentioned a class with id="txt"

```
<p id="txt">1</p>
```

I need to add 1 per every 500miliseconds interval. 
I used the following code but it didnot work.

```
function timedText() {
    var x = document.getElementById('txt');

    setInterval(function () {x= "(parseInt(x, 10)+ 1).toString(10)";},500);


}
```

The above function is called when a button is clicked.

Comment: What you did now was change the variable content, not the content of the `<p>` element. If you want to change the text inside the `<p>` element, you need to use `innerHTML` (`innerText` and `textContent` are also an option, but these can behave differently in different browsers).

Besides that, functions and constructors will not work if you write them as a string. You don't need to use those double quotes.

Comment: @DarkAshelin, I did see you editing my post and I wasn't sure if it was intentional or not. I would've accepted the edit had it been the way I wanted to explain my answer. Anyway, I didn't want you to think I was being rude, so I'm dropping a note here. xo

Comment: @naomik ah, I figured you didn't notice the suggested edit since you were mini-editing inbetween (which always overwrote my edit). So I just gave up after a couple of tries xD Apparently it's a thing to post short answers quick, and then keep expanding them (as opposite to posting a complete answer from the start). I didn't know that.

Comment: @DarkAshelin yeah. I usually give a bare minimum answer first so the OP can get what they need right away. Then I'll expand it to include a more detailed solution. And if I'm feeling ambitious, I'll go back and add explanations as needed so that a wider audience can benefit from the info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript does not support [string interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). I don't think you intended to use it, but anything within single quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) will not be evaluated by JavaScript.

To properly increment the value in your P tag, you will need this

```
// valid
x.innerHTML = (parseInt(x.innerHTML, 10)+ 1).toString(10);
```

**Not** this

```
// invalid
x = "(parseInt(x, 10)+ 1).toString(10)";
```

---

The above solution is pretty short-sighted, though. It couples your element, the counter increment, and the counter's delay all within a single function call. Not to mention, we're re-parsing the string to get the integer each time we increment.

What if we wrap a little object around this that keeps the counter value in a variable? The object could also contain its own interval function and corresponding interval timer.

Let's see what that might look like

```
function Counter(elem, delay) {
  var value = parseInt(elem.innerHTML, 10);
  var interval;

  function increment() {
    return value += 1; // This 1 could be turned into a variable that allows
                       // us to count by any value we want. I'll leave that
                       // as a lesson for you !
  }

  function updateDisplay(value) {
    elem.innerHTML = value;
  }

  function run() {
    updateDisplay(increment());
  }

  function start() {
    interval = window.setInterval(run, delay);
  }

  // exports
  // This actually creates a function that our counter can call
  // you'll see it used below.
  //
  // The other functions above cannot be accessed from outside
  // this function.
  this.start = start;
}
```

Of course this `Counter` could be *vastly* simplified, but this demonstrates good separation of concerns. The Counter is initializes with the elements starting `innerHTML` and all operations of the counter are nicely divided into single-purpose functions. You can use this same approach for building much more complex objects, but still keep the code very sane and reusable.

---

Now you can use your counter on any element

```
// get element
var elem = document.getElementById("txt");

// create counter with element and delay of 500ms
var counter = new Counter(elem, 500);

// start the counter
counter.start();
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/22rv14ny/3/)

Answer (score 2):

i have built on @user633183 answer and created this jsfiddle

it switches titles according to the timer he created. maybe its useful for others as well

```
function Counter(elem, delay) {
var value = parseInt(elem.getAttribute("value"), 10);
var interval;

var titles = [
    "hello i am the first title",
    "whats up, i am the second title",
    "add here any extra titles you want"
];

function updateDisplay(value) {
    elem.innerHTML = value;
}

function run() {
    value += 1;
    if (value == titles.length) value = 0;

    elem.setAttribute("value", value);
    updateDisplay(titles[value]);
}

function start() {
    interval = window.setInterval(run, delay);
}

// exports
// This actually creates a function that our counter can call
// you'll see it used below.
//
// The other functions above cannot be accessed from outside
// this function.
this.start = start;
}

var elem = document.getElementById("title-switcher");

counter = new Counter(elem, 2000);
counter.start();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shacharoz/Lhu7rfza/)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting x again to a string not setting it's innerHTML

```
function timedText() {
  var x = document.getElementById('txt');
  setInterval(function () {
     //set the inner html, parse the value from the inner html as well
     x.innerHTML = (parseInt(x.innerHTML, 10) + 1);
  }, 500);
}
```

here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/sx6qw45y/